# how to fill certain percentage area of circle in color in html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have some 9 circles in my html page.Each circle has to be filled with certain color with certain percentage.I have drawn the circles using html5 canvas element.But i was only able to fill the enitre circle with a color and not certain percantage area.How can i achieve that?

Comment: Use the arc method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc

Comment: Sounds like they want a circle with a wedge indicating percent complete. Maybe something like this but with wedges instead of arcs: https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/mYKp5/  ... Just Guessing :-/

Answer (score 17):

## "Fuel tank", filling of circle

Use composite mode:

- Use the radius x2 for height (or width)
- Draw and fill the complete circle
- Use composite mode `destination-out`
- Draw a filled rectangle on top representing the % of the height

The main code would be:

```
  var o = radius * 2,                 // diameter => width and height of rect
      h = o - (o * percent / 100);    // height based on percentage

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 6.28);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  ctx.fillRect(x - radius, y - radius, o, h);       // this will remove a part of the top
```

### Demo

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    pst = 0, dlt = 2;

ctx.fillStyle = "#28f";

function drawCircle(ctx, x, y, radius, percent) {

  var o = radius * 2,
      h = o - (o * percent / 100);
  
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";     // make sure we have default mode
  ctx.beginPath();                                  // fill an arc
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 6.28);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"; // mode to use for next op.
  ctx.fillRect(x - radius, y - radius, o, h);       // "clear" part of arc
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";     // be polite, set default mode back
}

(function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,150);
  drawCircle(ctx, 70, 70, 60, pst);
  pst += dlt;
  if (pst <= 0 || pst >= 100) dlt = -dlt;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

## Pie type

- Move to center of circle
- Add arc, this will create a line from center to start of arc
- Close path, this will create a line from end of arc back to center, and fill

(tip: `closePath()` is really not necessary with `fill()` as `fill()` will close the path implicit, but it's needed if you want to do a `stroke()` instead).

The essential part being:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, y);
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI * percent / 100);
//ctx.closePath();  // for stroke, not needed for fill
ctx.fill();
```

### Demo

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    pst = 0, dlt = 2;

ctx.fillStyle = "#28f";

function drawPie(ctx, x, y, radius, percent) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI * percent /100);
  ctx.fill();
}

(function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,150); drawPie(ctx, 70, 70, 60, pst);
  pst += dlt; if (pst <= 0 || pst >= 100) dlt = -dlt;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

## Outlined circle:

Almost same as with pie type, but with these changes:

- Move to outer edge of arc at angle 0 (or the angle you want to start from)
- Add arc to path
- Stroke (remember to set `lineWidth`, see demo below)

Essential part:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);  // cos(0) for x = 1, so just use radius, sin(0) = 0
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI * percent /100);
ctx.stroke();
```

You can adjust gap point using rotation transform or calculating the actual point using trigonometry.

### Demo

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    pst = 0, dlt = 2;

ctx.strokeStyle = "#28f";
ctx.lineWidth = 8;

function drawWedge(ctx, x, y, radius, percent) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI * percent /100);
  ctx.stroke();
}

(function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,150); drawWedge(ctx, 70, 70, 60, pst);
  pst += dlt; if (pst <= 0 || pst >= 100) dlt = -dlt;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

## Using different starting point

You can change the starting point for the arc using rotation transform or calculating the point manually using trigonometry.

To calculate these manually you can do (angles in radians):

```
x = radius * Math.cos(angleInRad);  // end point for x
y = radius * Math.sin(angleInRad);  // end point for y
```

Just add the total angle to the start angle to get end point.

360° in radians = 2 x PI, so if you want to use angles in degrees, convert them using:

```
angleInRad = angleInDeg * Math.PI / 180;
```

### Demo, rotated using transfrom and counter-clock-wise mode

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    pst = 0, dlt = 2;

ctx.strokeStyle = "#28f";
ctx.lineWidth = 8;

function drawWedge(ctx, x, y, radius, percent) {
  ctx.translate(x, y);        // translate to rotating pivot
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI * 0.5);  // rotate, here 90° deg
  ctx.translate(-x, -y);      // translate back
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI * percent /100);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
}

(function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,150); drawWedge(ctx, 70, 70, 60, pst);
  pst += dlt; if (pst <= 0 || pst >= 100) dlt = -dlt;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```