# How to create outline of circle that increases by 1/365 part each day of the year?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Rather new to JavaScript and I'm trying to complete this project:

Inside a circle there will be a counter ticking up from 1 to 365, once per day, so at the time of writing it would say "5/365". I've worked out how to do this.

I also want the full circle to have a thin outline, which I assume you'd create with canvas. The tricky part is that I want a thicker outline to fill the circle at the same pace as the counter inside of it increases, so today 5/365 parts of it would be thick. Does that make sense?

I've managed to create the inside counter and the thin outline, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978648/how-to-fill-certain-percentage-area-of-circle-in-color-in-html-canvas) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440732/canvas-fill-a-specific-area-of-an-arc-circle) as inspiration but still struggle.

The small amount of code I have so far:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250,250,200,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

window.onload=function() {
    // Month,Day,Year,Hour,Minute,Second
    upTime('dec,31,2017,00:00:00');
}    

var today, someday, difference;
function upTime(someday) {
    today = new Date();
    someday = new Date(someday);
    difference = (today - someday);

    var days = Math.floor(difference / (1000*60*60*24)*1);
    document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days;

    clearTimeout(upTime.to);
    upTime.to = setTimeout(function() { upTime(someday); },0); 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<p><span id="days">0</span>/365</p>
```

Thanks in advance!
/Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

You can create an thicker arc that overlaps the outline. Set [`ctx.lineWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineWidth) to the desired pixel width. Set the radius so that your thicker arc overlaps the outline. For instance, match the radii and double `lineWidth` on the thicker arc.

Then, to denote the amount of time passed, vary the `endAngle` parameter for the thicker arc [(mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc).

The only tricky thing is that `startAngle` and `endAngle` are expressed in radians. A complete circle is `2*Math.PI` radians; a quarter-circle is `Math.PI/2` Depending on how you'd like your clock to display, you might have to offset `startAngle` by a quarter-circle (otherwise it starts at the positive-X axis, or 3pm on a normal clock.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly:

You could do something like this :

1. create a circle (say radius 100 for ease of understanding) with 1 line width and a filled background
2. calculate the number of days passed (that you are doing already), and convert that into percent (that's y 100 as the radius to map days to radius, you can use any formula)
3. Draw a circle with background color white inside the first circle with radius of (100 - days percent calculated in 2nd step)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 100;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeStyle = 'green';
context.stroke();

function fillDays(days){
 var per = (days/365)*100;
 context.beginPath();
 context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius - per, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 context.fillStyle = 'white';
 context.fill();
 context.lineWidth = 1;
 context.strokeStyle = 'green';
 context.stroke();
}

window.onload = function() {
var from = new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear()-1, 11, 31); //last day of the previous year
        upTime(from, new Date());
}

var today, someday, difference;

function upTime(someday, todate) {
    difference = (todate - someday);

    var days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * 1);
    document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days;
    fillDays(days);
    clearTimeout(upTime.to);
    if(days<365){
    upTime.to = setTimeout(function() {
        upTime(someday, new Date(todate.setDate(todate.getDate()+1)));
    }, 50)
    };
}
```

```html
<span id="days">0</span>/365
<canvas id="canvas" height="210" width="210"></canvas>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Maybe you want something like this:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 100;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.lineWidth = 3;
context.strokeStyle = 'green';
context.stroke();

function fillDays(days){
 var startingRad = -Math.PI/2; //from which position to start in rad
  var deg = (days/365)*360;
  var rad = (Math.PI/180) * deg;
 context.beginPath();
 context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius-15, startingRad, rad+startingRad, false);
 context.lineWidth = 30;
 context.strokeStyle = 'green';
 context.stroke();
}

window.onload = function() {
var from = new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear()-1, 11, 31); //last day of the previous year
        upTime(from, new Date());
}

var today, someday, difference;

function upTime(someday, todate) {
    difference = (todate - someday);
    var days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * 1);
    document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days;
    fillDays(days);
    clearTimeout(upTime.to);
    if(days<365){
    upTime.to = setTimeout(function() {
        upTime(someday, new Date(todate.setDate(todate.getDate()+1)));
    }, 50)
    };
}
```

```html
<span id="days">0</span>/365 days
<canvas id="canvas" height="210" width="210"></canvas>
```

Comment: I see what you're trying to do and I'm thinking that I might use this instead of what I originally suggested (which I now realize might have been a little unclear). What I was trying to say was that the thicker line will have a set line width and increase clockwise by one part every day. Sorry for being unclear and thanks for taking the time to reply, I do really like the idea you have too!

Comment: @BenjaminRowntree have a look at the new code that i added in the answer

Comment: Timeout I have added is just a demo, you can fine-tune it, just don't keep zero like you have in your question.